App Data set to Persisted don't display in Test Mode in Flutterflow
I am using Flutterflow, and trying to implement a ListView of Search History terms in the SearchPage.
The problem is that when the History App Data (a list of strings) is set to Persisted, the whole ListView does not display in TestMode.
Setting History to not Persisted makes it display, but defeats the purpose of that function.
I have encountered the same issue before while following this lesson.
Has anyone else come across this issue? How did you solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Have you reached a solution?
